# How to get only first two digits of seconds in a time converter function

Tags: javascript, jquery, seconds

I have the following function, that converts seconds to hours, minutes and seconds, the issue is, the second section of the output is sometimes very long digits such as `01:10:20453578970`.
I want to trim it to two digit for each section, like `01:10:20`.

```js
function getReadableTime(value) {
  hours = Math.floor(value / 3600);
  value %= 3600;
  minutes = Math.floor(value / 60);
  seconds = value % 60;
  return hours + ":" +minutes+ ":" +seconds;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: And what value causes that to happen?

Comment: `seconds.toString().slice(0,2)`

Comment: What does jQuery have to do with this? Can you provide a snippet that *produces* that output?

Comment: @adeneo thank you for your solution. I can approve it if you submit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that your function can return a number of seconds that is 60 or more. I suppose you are speaking of the number of hours that indeed can get more than 2 digits.

To get the number of hours since midnight (instead of since 1970, for instance), add one more statement at the start of your function:

```js
function getReadableTime(value) {
    // truncate value, and only count since midnight
    value = Math.floor(value) % (3600*24);
    var hours = Math.floor(value / 3600);
    value %= 3600;
    var minutes = Math.floor(value / 60);
    var seconds = value % 60;
    // prefix single digits with a zero
    return (hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds).replace(/\b\d\b/g, '0$&');
}

var elapsed = getReadableTime(1497031554);
console.log(elapsed);
```

NB: always make any newly introduced variables local with `var` (or `let`, `const`).